# Changing state does nothing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to go back at a sibling state, as I did a lot of times in my Ionic app. But this time it just doesn't want to do it.

Here's where I'm calling the `$state`:

```
dataProvider.custom('/api/cats/' + catId + '/',
                {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    },
                    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                            formData.append(key, value);
                        });
                        headers = headersGetter();
                        delete headers['Content-Type'];
                        return formData;
                    }
                })
                .then(function (resp) {
                    $state.go('^.cat', {'cat': catId});
                });
```

And here are my states :

```
$stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
        })
        .state('menu', {
            url: '/menu',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
            onEnter: function($state, Auth){
                if(!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            }
        })
        .state('menu.home', {
            url: '/devel',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/devel.html',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('menu.catspad', {
            url: '/catspad',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/catspad.html',
                    controller: 'CatspadCtrl',
                }
            }
        })

        .state('menu.cats', {
            url: '/cats',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/cats.html',
                    controller: 'CatsCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        items: ['dataProvider', function (dataProvider) {
                            return dataProvider.fetch('/api/cats/')
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .state('menu.cat', {
            url: '/cat/view/{cat:int}',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/cat.html',
                    controller: 'CatDetailCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        items: ['dataProvider', '$stateParams', function(dataProvider, $stateParams) {
                            return dataProvider.fetch('/api/cats/' + $stateParams.cat + '/detail/');
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        .state('menu.catAddChange', {
            url: '/cat/addchange?cat',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/catAddChange.html',
                    controller: 'CatAddChangeCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        items: ['dataProvider', '$stateParams', function(dataProvider, $stateParams)
                        {
                            if ($stateParams.cat) {
                                return dataProvider.fetch('/api/cats/' + $stateParams.cat + '/detail/')
                            }}]
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        .state('menu.me', {
            url: '/me',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
                    controller: 'AccountCtrl',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: 'templates/register.html'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/menu/cats');
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition("none");
```

Relevant HTML :

main.html (abstract state)

```
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" class="customViewStyle"></ion-nav-view>
```

catAddChange.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="Change or add a cat"  class="animated slideInUp">
```

Everything works fine everywhere but here... What's happening?

Comment: Could you add `concole.log(catId);` just before your `$state.go('^.cat', {'cat': catId});`? Because if parameter is undefined there will no errors.

Comment: Did it, catId is `1`.

Comment: Ok. Could you also put `console.log` in your resolve section(in menu.cat state) and inside your CatDetailCtrl?

Comment: Sure, the `console.log` doesn't trigger in resolve, and displays 1 in `CatDetailCtrl`

Comment: It's strange. What's happen next? Does the page rendered? Any errors in the console? Are the 'items' presented?

Comment: Well, as I try to fix, behavior changes. When using `$state.go` it literally does nothing. When using `ui-sref` in template it fallback to the `otherwise` paramter of the `$stateProvider`. Using `ui-sref` that way :  `ui-sref="menu.cat({cat: catId})"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was on the type of the parameter given to the `menu.cat` state.

After debugging with `typeof`, the `catId` type was `string`, therefore not accepted by the state since it was expecting an `int`...

To summarize, I needed to ensure the parameter's type is as the `state` expects (`int` here). It will not work if it receives `"1"` (string) instead of 1(number), **without any error at all**.

It was hard to find this, hope this will help.

Comment: Actually, my first question was about parameter's type. I'm sure that in the console you've got `"1"` and NOT `1`.

Comment: `console.log()` prints `1` in both cases, just tested it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm surprised that even `console.log("1");`' prints `1`.